# How to know if a List<Object> is modified or an item changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

I have a `List<>` that is populate with data of a database, after of that an event of a gridview is activated. Then the items of the list can be modified, changed or eliminated.

Then I want to know how I can determinate if this item or items was altered without go to the database, if this is possible?

The data in the aspx page is in a Gridview.

Comment: Do you mean if the underlying database records were changed or if the items in the List<> were changed?

Comment: Why not store 2 identical lists to start with and just compare the two after you think one has been altered

Comment: If you change by the GridView, you can implement some events of Gridview and code something there to log what you changed, for sample.

Comment: The control should raise events if a row is changed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at `ObservableCollection` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself. It is hard to come up with a proper answer if we have no code to look at though.

Comment: @St0ffer: `It is hard to come up with a proper answer if we have no code to look at though.` true, but `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not help in case of ASP.NET...

Comment: @ChrFin Oh yeah, I was a bit too fast there, you are right. Though I read somewhere that it is possible to implement a similar MVVM approach in ASP.NET with INotifyPropertyChanged but I have no idea how since I am a total utter noob in ASP.

Comment: Alex the items in the List<>.!

Comment: @ZoomVirus that can be a posibility. I will studied it.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server, you can use SqlDependency in order to get notified of any changes to the data initially retrieved.  Be aware that there are some restrictions on the associated SqlCommand (e.g. single statement, no LEFT JOINs, etc.).  SqlDependency is implemented with QueryNotifications and Service Broker, so the SQL Server database must have Service Broker enabled.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx.